# How to draw BarPlot or Histogram using Subplot in MatplotLib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

- I want to draw Grid of **Bar graph/Histogram** for my data.My Data contains **1 NUMERIC and 3 CATEGORICAL Column**
- PAIRGraph is not suitable for my purpose as my purpose as I have only 1 Numeric and 3 Categorical Column

Tried to Refer Documentation https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

However, I am unable to find exact way to fulfill my requirement.

Using Demo code I am able to draw only LineGraph. However, I am required to draw Bar Graph.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,4))
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 11)
axes[0].plot(x, x**2, x, np.exp(x),x,20*x)
axes[0].set_title("Normal scale")
axes[0].plot

axes[1].plot(x, x**2, x, np.exp(x))
axes[1].set_yscale("log")
axes[1].set_title("Logarithmic scale (y)");
```

Please feel free to correct my approach or guide me as I have just started learning.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify exactly what you want to use for the `bar` and `hist`, I can modify, but generally it is simply changing the `plot` to the type of chart you need

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,4))
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 11)
axes[0].bar(x,x**2) # bar plot
axes[0].set_title("Normal scale")
axes[0].plot

axes[1].hist(x) # histogram
axes[1].set_yscale("log")
axes[1].set_title("Logarithmic scale (y)");

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I am new to this subject. Your help was very encouraging.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the API documentation from Matplotlip Subplot Axes, I found ways to draw different graph not just Line graph.

https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html

**DEFAULT:-**

- `axes[0].plot` by-default draws line graph.

**CUSTOM GRAPH:-**

- `axes[0].bar` can be used to draw **BAR graph** in selected **Subplot**
- `axes[0].scatter` can be used to draw **Scatter graph** in selected **Subplot**
- `axes[0].hist` can be used to draw a **histogram**. in selected **Subplot**

Like above example more graph can be drawn with below API:- 
[image]